# The name of the Everyone group in non-english OSs

Tags: c#, globalization

We have an issue with the way we are creating a `Mutex`. The problem line is:

```
MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule("Everyone", MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

The hardcoded "Everyone" string only works on English OSes, how do we change this line so it works in all languages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google is being helpful today:

Looks like [this will help](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FindingOutTheNameOfTheEVERYONEGroupOnANonenglishInternationalVersionOfWindows.aspx)

This code solves this problem:

```
  SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
  MutexAccessRule rule = new MutexAccessRule(sid, MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

VB:

```
Dim sid As System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier = New System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, Nothing)
Dim rule As System.Security.AccessControl.MutexAccessRule = New System.Security.AccessControl.MutexAccessRule(sid, System.Security.AccessControl.MutexRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but needed the actual localized string of the "Everyone" group name in order to enable access to a MessageQueue. Here's the solution I found, which works fine:

```
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var acct = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;
myMessageQueue.SetPermissions(acct.ToString(), MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl);
```